# Use interpolation/Variables in file_get_contents - PHP

Tags: php, html

I am making a website with PHP (5.4), I think that I will be going to update things like the PHP code and the design in the website, so, I did not want to change every file when I make an a update.  Then I thought that if I use the `file_get_contents` function to get the content of a file that had the navbar HTML,CSS,JS and PHP code, and I jut change that file content in the update, it will be easier and faster. Except for the problem that in the parts where I tried to use interpolation in the file:

**Interpolation in PHP:** Make this:

```
$myVar = "myVarText";
$interpolation_var = "The var \"myVar\" content is : $myvar";
echo $interpolation_var;
```

**Returned text:** The var "myVar" content is : myVarText

It just ignored that and it also shows it like plain text. I tried everything, even this:

```
$file_content = "".file_get_content("path/to/file.txt")."";
```

So if somebody have a solution for this, answer this question with that, please.

Comment: Use include instead http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: To rjdown: That is not what i am looking for for, i am looking for a way where i can print all the file content with interpolation

Answer (score 1):

Use [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) and just `include()` it to inherit variables from the current scope:

```
ob_start();
include("path/to/file.txt");
$file_content = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat a little hack I came up with while working on project.
*(I wanted a .html template for conversion to .pdf that I can debug in browser but also use it directly with full variable interpolation later in my php code for mPdf from html creation. Aaaand I did not want to use the ugly `<?php echo $whatever;>` allover in the html to use the `ob_start(); include("myfile.html"); $var = ob_get_clean();` trick, since a browser wont render the php tags in an .html file anyway. See original at the end.)*

If you can alter the .txt from this:

```
The var \"myVar\" content is : $myvar
```

... to that:

```
<?php $interpolation_var="The var \"myVar\" content is : $myvar";
```

This way the .txt file pretends to be a vaild .php file. Now you can just use an include / require in your php and you have full variable interpolation:

```
$myVar = "myVarText";
include "theTxtFile.txt";
echo $interpolation_var;
```

**Outputs** `The var "myVar" content is : myVarText`

---

*As for the original issue I had: Most browser nowadays will cope with the ill html and display the page just fine with the $vars as plain text*

```
<?php $html="/><!-- This is a little hack to display as pure html for easier debugging but pretend to be a php file with one variable for php includes -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
 <meta charset='UTF-8'>
 <title></title>
 <style type='text/css'>
 * {outline: 1px solid #f005;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>    
 <p>hello $myvar gets interpolated $thisAlso[red].</p>    
</body>
</html>";
```

**Browser output** `hallo $myvar gets interpolated $thisAlso[red].`

*The php code for mPdf from html creation. All variables are interpolated*

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$myvar = "apple";
$thisAlso = ["red" => "juice"];
require_once "theHacked.html";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

**Pdf output** `hello apple gets interpolated juice.`